# Calculating $\Delta x$ for electron when kinetic energy of electron is known

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

### Excercise:

Electron has kinetic energy of $K=4.80KeV$ and it is known with $1.00\%$ of accuracy.

How large/small is  momentum relative error $\frac{\Delta p}{p}$ ?

How accurately electron position  $\Delta x$ can be measured ?

### Attempt to solve:

we can calculate momentum with

$$ p=m\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}} $$

$$ \frac{\Delta p}{p} = \quad ?? $$

to my understanding you're suppose to derivate p with respect to variable p ?

---

Problem is i don't know how does this sort of differential equation work ? I do know how to derivate function / equation with respect to a variable. This might be more of a math question than physics but if someone could help me with this that would be highly appreciated. If someone could just point me in right direction how to calculate relative error.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting elsewhere, e.g., at the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You know from the excercise K. So you can find the momentum:
\begin{equation}
p=\sqrt{2m_{e}K}
\end{equation}
You know also the accuracy, $\alpha$, of measurement and therefore the uncertainty $\Delta K$.
\begin{equation}
\Delta K=a K
\end{equation}
By error propagation, then, you can find $\Delta p$ (think like deriving p, with respect to K).
\begin{equation}
\Delta p=\sqrt{\frac{m_e}{2 K}}\Delta K
\end{equation}
So you know  $\frac{\Delta p}{p}$. Finally, using uncertainty principle, you will get $\Delta x$.
\begin{equation}
\Delta x\approx \frac{\hbar}{\Delta p}
\end{equation}